# Check how many mails have come in per day

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server

We have a syncronisation problem and i've been tasked with writing a program in c# that counts the number of mails that have come in per day on a number of mailboxes on an exchange server(2-5)

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, Blackberry Enterprise Server does something similar in order to forward your emails to your blackberry.  Basically you need to create a windows service based MAPI client.  Whether you SHOULD do this is another matter, it seems like you are trying to fix a systems issue with a nasty hack.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest solution would be to [analyze your smtp logs using Logparser](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2007/11/12/3404342.aspx). The linked article refers to Exchange 2007 but this should still apply to Exchange 2010.